# Help with my project on motors using the Arduino Board

Tags: arduino-uno

I was given the task of being able to drive two motors in the forward direction, able to drive two motors in the reverse direction, and they must be able to drive each motor independently. I was wondering if anyone can give me directions, advice, or tips on the coding for this task. All I know is that:
if(switchState == HIGH){
digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
}
else{
digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
}
}
I know this code makes the motor turn on and off with the high and low, but what type of code do I use to make it work at a certain speed, and to move independently?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. Please be aware that this is not a free design house or an on-demand online technical encyclopedia. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: `given the task` .... is this school work?

Comment: There are plenty oft tutorials in the web. Google and follow one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PWM function of digital pins (analogWrite())to control the motor speeds as desired.